# jquery mobile listview refresh doesn't refilter jqm 1.4

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filter

I have a listview using the data-input property to provide a filter.  After I dynamically change the listview, I call listview refresh.  Even though there is still text in the filter input, the filter is not applied.  You can see the problem in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Pqe9/3/

Here is the html that sets it up:

```
<div id="aPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
            <input data-type="search" type="text" id="aFilter" />
        </form>
        <ul id="aList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#aFilter">
            <li>aaa</li><li>bbb</li>
        </ul>
        <a data-role='button' href='#bpage'>test</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role='page' id='bpage'>
    <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back" data-role="button">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the dynamic load and refresh that runs when you return to the page:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#aPage', function() {
    $('#aList li').remove();
    $('#aList').append($("<li>").append('aaa'));
    $('#aList').append($("<li>").append('bbc'));
    $("#aList").listview('refresh');
});
```

Filter, then click the test button, then go back and you'll see that the filter doesn't work.  I've tried triggering a change function on the filter, but that doesn't work either.  Any ideas how I can get the listview to filter again based on the input?

Comment: Note the changes in js code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7Pqe9/6/

Comment: The problem with your changes is that I don't want to clear the filter, I want to keep the existing filter

Comment: `data-filter="true"` is deprecated as of 1.4 and will removed on 1.5 you better use _filterable_ widget in 1.4.

Comment: I am using filterable widget.  And although they say data-filter="true" is deprecated, the filterable widget doesn't filter without it

Comment: in this case you need to use `.filterable("refresh")`. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971913/jquery-mobile-search-option/20972589#20972589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omar's last comment above worked.  I didn't realize there was a separate widget that I should call refresh on.

```
$("#aList").filterable("refresh");
```

That keeps the existing filter and refreshes the list to reflect the results of the filter.

Thanks.